# MPICH2 Hydra round robin on multicore

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, mpich

I need to schedule process in round robin order in my Mpi program.

I have a cluster with 8 nodes, each cluster with quad-core processor.
I use mpich2-1.4.1p1 version under Ubuntu Linux.

If using this machinefile :

```
node01
node02
node03
node04
node05
node06
node07
node08
```

and then run :

```
mpiexec -np 10 -machinefile host ./my-program
```

I have a right scheduling, rank 0 to node01, rank1 to node02, ... rank8 to node01 and finally rank 9 to node02

But I need to know if rank 0 and rank 8 run on same core or not. I need that rank 0 works on first core on node01 and rank 8 on second.

If I use a different machinefile :

```
node01:4
node02:4
node03:4
node04:4
node05:4
node06:4
node07:4
node08:4
```

and then run :

```
mpiexec -np 10 -machinefile host2 ./my-program
```

I have that rank 0,1,2,3 run on node01 . And isn't what I want.

How force Hydra to use round robin on node first and then on cores using this second machinefile ?

Comment: Try passing `-rr` to `mpiexec` in you second case.

Comment: [mpiexec@node02] HYDU_parse_array (/home/user/opt/install_pack/mpich2-1.4.1p1/src/pm/hydra/utils/args/args.c:140): argument matching returned error

Comment: Then try using the first host file (with no slots specified) and provide the `-binding rr` option to `mpiexec`.

Comment: but first host file works with round robin scheduling, in fact using -binding rr code give me same outputs. Output of first host file is good for me, but I must be sure that process at rank 0 and process at rank 8 are executing by different core of node01 and not by same core. If there is a function for print id of core I can solve this problem. Something like MPI_Get_processor_name for core exists ?

Comment: That's what `-binding rr` should achieve - rank 0 should be bound to CPU 0 and rank 1 should be bound to CPU 1. Unfortunately `MPI_Get_processor_name` would give you only the host name. To get the process binding you could open `/proc/self/status`, read it line by line until you hit the line that starts with `Cpus_allowed` and print its content - this is the CPU mask for the process. Or you can just log into the node and use `taskset` to examine the affinity masks for both processes as they run.

Comment: Another option would be to use `mpiexec` to launch a script that prints the hostname and does `grep ^Cpus_allowed /proc/$$/status`.

Comment: in Cpus_allowed I read ff ... what means ? 
I not understand how this give me core information...

Comment: If it reads `ff`, then no process to CPU binding is being performed, so both processes are free to move to whatever CPU(s) the OS deems fit.